# process command and the percent sign usage

Tags: kill, jobs

I am confused about stopping a job by using the percent sign with the kill command. I cannot find any documentation in the man pages for kill that indicate the percent sign can be used. Can someone explain to me if this explanation is hidden somewhere else, or why the `%` sign is used?

`kill -s 19 %1` would stop the job with an id of 1

Comment: `man bash` .. JOB CONTROL

Answer (score 16):

The `%` sign introduces a [job specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_(Unix)). To put it simply, a job is a process that has been started by the shell and can be running in the foreground (if it is, then you can't interact with the shell), running in the background, suspended, or already dead (but the shell hasn't noticed yet, otherwise the job would go away).

`%1` means the job which is the first entry in that shell's job table. Job numbers in different shell instances are unrelated, and they're unrelated to the process ID. You can use the `jobs` command to see a list of jobs in that shell. Other useful commands to manipulate jobs are `fg` and `bg`, to move a job to the foreground or background respectively. Other ways to manipulate jobs are pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend the foreground job and running a command with `&` at the end to send it directly into the background.

There is an independent `kill` utility, and also a shell builtin called `kill`. The command exists as a separate utility so that it can be invoked from other programs without launching a shell. The command exists as a shell builtin so that it can be invoked even if there aren't enough resources left to launch a `kill` process, and so that it can understand shell internal data structures.

Jobs are an internal shell data structure, so the external `kill` command doesn't know about them. The man page documents the external command. To find documentation about `kill` features related to jobs, look at the documentation of your shell, for example [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-kill) or [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-kill). Then refer to the section about jobs: [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Job-Control-Basics), [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Jobs-_0026-Signals.html#Jobs). The shell manual is also where the commands `jobs`, `fg` and `bg` are documented.

Comment: What's the difference between `fg 1` and `fg %1` ?

Comment: @ChristopherMarkieta In `fg %1`, the number after the `%` is a job number. What `fg 1` means depends on the shell. For example bash treats it like `fg %1`; ksh looks for a job with PID 1; dash and zsh don't recognize `1` as a valid job designation.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to refer to a job in the shell. The character % introduces a job specification (jobspec). Job number n may be referred to as %n. A job may also be referred to using a prefix of the name used to start it, or using a substring that appears in its command line.
Simply naming a job can be used to bring it into the foreground: %1 is a synonym for ''fg %1'', bringing job 1 from the background into the foreground. Similarly, ''%1 &'' resumes job 1 in the background, equivalent to ''bg %1''.

Answer (score -1):

```
[root@typhoon ~]# jobs
[3]+  Stopped                 sleep 3000
[5]-  Stopped                 sleep 1001
[6]   Running                 sleep 9922 &

[root@typhoon ~]# /bin/kill %5
kill: cannot find process "%5"

[root@typhoon ~]# kill %5
[root@typhoon ~]#
```